# Suppose $\angle BAC = 60^\circ$ and $\angle ABC = 20^\circ$. A point $E$ inside $ABC$ satisfies $\angle EAB=20^\circ$ and $\angle ECB=30^\circ$.

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

**Problem statement:**

> *In a triangle $ABC$ with angles $\angle BAC = 60^\circ$ and $\angle ABC = 20^\circ$, a point $E$ inside the triangle is given such that $\angle EAB = 20^\circ$ and $\angle ECB = 30^\circ$. Prove that $E$ lies on an angle bisector of $\angle ABC$*.

I drew a picture in Geogebra for this problem and this is what I did so far:
[image]

All angles drawn were found out by using the fact that the sum of angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$. I also noticed that $AD=BD$, $AC=CD=AE$ by using isosceles triangles.

I tried proving that $E$ lies on an angle bisector of $\angle ABC$ by proving that $GE=EI$ and so I drew perpendicular bisectors from $E$ to the sides $AB$ and $BC$, and I noticed two pairs of similar triangles: $\triangle AHE \sim \triangle AEF$ and $\triangle CJE \sim \triangle CED$, but I'm not sure if this is useful in any way.

I'm stuck since and I don't know how to continue on from this. I'm not sure if this is even the right approach to the problem. Is there a way of approaching this problem that I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a good, accepted answer due to [ole](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/725731/ole), and after seeing it i waited to have it accepted. Since i started an answer focusing on (three more or less) different ways to attack the problem, and did a lot of pictures, i had a hard decision to still post or delete the work. For the reason that it still be interesting for some readers i completed the answer.  A note before the solutions come. There is a complicated solution still added, it is similar in its construction with the known "Langley problem".

---

**1.st solution:**
This first solution is in its nature the same [ole](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/725731/ole)'s solution, it uses but an equilateral triangle to perform the "mule" from one direction to an other one, and comes with a picture.

We construct on $CE$ an equilateral triangle $\Delta CDE$, so that its angle bisector in $C$ is the line $CB$. Let also in this triangle $C'$, $D'$ be the mid points of the sides opposite to $C$, $D$.
Let $F$ be the projection of $E$ on $AB$.

[image: Mathematics stackexchange problem 3795377]

Then $\Delta CAE$ is isosceles having the angles in $C,E$ of the same measure, $70^\circ$, which implies $\Delta ACD'=\Delta AED'=\Delta AEF$. So $EC'=ED'=EF$.

$\square$

---

As a digression, it is maybe interesting to see in the context of the "bigger picture" of the equilateral triangle on $AB$ where are the points of the solution, e.g. the point $D$. No comment:

[image: Problem 3795377 mathematics stackexchange]

---

**2.nd solution:** Using the trigonometric version of the theorem of Ceva, we have to show the equality:
$$
1\overset!=
\frac{\sin20^\circ}{\sin40^\circ}\cdot
\frac{\sin70^\circ}{\sin30^\circ}\cdot
\frac{\sin10^\circ}{\sin10^\circ}\ .
$$
This is immediate using
$\sin 40^\circ =2\sin 20^\circ \cos 20^\circ  $.

$\square$

---

**3.rd solution:**
An other solution which is often self-suggested in such cases is to realize the given triangle as a "part" of a regular polygon, then use the symmetries inside this polygon. This may seem to be an overkill for a solution, producing the most complex picture, but it may be the right structural perspective to understand why there exist such "coincidences", how "many" they are, and how to construct / compose similar problems.

As a comparison, consider Langley's problem, which has many simple solutions, but there is also...

[the stackexchange questions 1121534](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121534/calculating-the-angle-of-a-triangle)

In our case, the transposition is...

[image: Mathematics stackexchange 3795377 regular polygon]

The given triangle configuration is embedded inside a regular polygon as $\Delta (0,2,12)$. We want to show that the diagonals $0-9$; $2-14$, $4-16$, $1-12$, $6-17$ are concurrent in $E$.

We are now performing the following transformation, that brings the regular $18$-gons from the following picture in each other:

[image: Mathematics stackexchange 3795377 transformation]

Using as center the point $9$ we use first a rotation that moves $1$ to $0$, then use a similarity which brings the length of the segment $[9,13]$ into the length of the segment $[9,12]$. Of course, we can revert the order of the rotation and homothety without change. To have a quick visual aid of the transformation, two triangles were marked. The red triangle $\Delta(9,13,1)$ is transformed into the blue triangle
$\Delta(9',13',1')=\Delta(9,12,1')$. This is so because $9=9'$, $9$ being the center of the rotation and stretching, and the segment $[9,13]$ is mapped to $[9',13']=[9,12]$ since the two segments are in the right angle and the right proportion. Let us identify $1'$ as the point $E$ from the problem.

- $9,1',0$ are colinear since both lines $90$ and $91'$ build the same angle w.r.t. $90'$.
- So $9,(k+1)',k$ are collinear for all other values of a vertex $k$.
- $1,1',12$ are colinear since $\angle (9,12,1)=\angle (9,13,1)=\angle (9',13',1')=\angle (9,12,1')$.
- In a similar manner, $k,k',12$ are collinear for all other values of a vertex $k$ and transformed vertex $k'$.
- The lines $1'-2'$ and $4-16$ coincide, this can be shown by using  the line through $12=13'$, $O'$, $4'$, $4$ or the parallel line $8-8'-12$ at same distance.

Yet an other picture.
[image: mathematics stackexchange 3795377 yet an other pic]

Answer (score 4):

$GE=1/2*CE (opposite 30), ACE isosceles (angles 70,70),draw perpendicular to CE, there are 2 congruent right triangles , angle 20,  common hypotenuse. So,  GE=EI.

Comment: Shouldn't it be that $IE=\frac{CE}{2}$ instead of $GE$? Other than that, this solution is the most elegant so far.

Comment: $IE=\frac{CE}{2}$ you are right

Answer (score 1):

Let $\angle EBC=\alpha$ and $\angle EBA=20^\circ-\alpha$. Using the trigonometric form of Ceva’s Theorem, we can see that $$\frac{sin(40^\circ)}{sin(20^\circ)}\cdot\frac{sin(20^\circ-\alpha)}{sin(\alpha)}\cdot\frac{sin(30^\circ)}{sin(70^\circ)}=1$$ Using double angle formula and some trigonometric identities we have $$\frac{2sin(20^\circ)cos(20^\circ)}{sin(20^\circ)} \cdot\frac{sin(20^\circ-\alpha)}{sin(\alpha)}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{cos(20^\circ)}=1$$ Which simplifes to $$sin(20^\circ-\alpha)=sin(\alpha)$$ Therefore we have $\alpha=10^\circ$ which means $E$ lies on an angle bisector.

Answer (score 0):

In your figure, let's use $\alpha=\angle CBE$ and $\beta=\angle ABE$. Then using law of sines in $\triangle CEB$: $$\frac{\sin\alpha}{CE}=\frac{\sin 30^\circ}{EB}$$
Similarly, in $\triangle EBA$:
$$\frac{\sin\beta}{AE}=\frac{\sin 20^\circ}{EB}$$
So $$\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}=\frac{\sin 30^\circ}{\sin20^\circ}\frac{CE}{AE}$$
We get the last ratio of lengths from $\triangle AEC$:
$$\frac{CE}{AC}=\frac{\sin 40^\circ}{\sin 70^\circ}$$
So $$\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}=\frac{\sin 30^\circ}{\sin20^\circ}\frac{\sin 40^\circ}{\sin 70^\circ}$$
Now using $$\sin 20^\circ\sin70^\circ=\frac 12\cos(20^\circ-70^\circ)\frac 12\cos(20^\circ+70^\circ)=\frac12\cos(50^\circ)=\frac12\sin40^\circ$$
and $\sin 30^\circ=\frac 12$, you get $$\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}=1$$or $\alpha=\beta$