# Let the triangle $ABC$ be $\angle A = 110°$ and $\angle B = 40°$. We consider a point $E$ . Show that $CA=CE$

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

**QUESTION**

Let the triangle $ABC$ be $\angle A = 110°$ and $\angle B = 40°$. We consider a point $E$ inside the triangle $ABC$ so that $\angle ECB = 10°$ and $\angle EBC=20°$. Show that $CA=CE$.

*my drawing*

[image]

**My ideas**

We can show that $\angle C= 30$.

I observed that $BE$ is the bisector of $\angle B$ and I thought of the propriety of the bisector points so I drew some perpendicular from $E$ on the $3$ sides of the triangle. We can see that $EY$ and $EX$ are congruent. The fact that we have some $30$ angles makes me think of the theorem of the $30$ angle.

$AZEY$ is an inscribed quadrilateral.

I don't know what to do further. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Do the arguments in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795377/suppose-angle-bac-60-circ-and-angle-abc-20-circ-a-point-e-inside?rq=1 help?

Comment: @Magdiragdag No, it doesn't. I don't think it is related at all to the problem I posted.

Comment: @lonelaBuciu$:$ See the answer of Lion Heart. I think this is the kind of answer you are looking for which is purely geometrical i.e. it does not involve any trigonometric identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct $\triangle BEF$ such that $\triangle BEF \cong \triangle BEC$ on side $AB$, point $F$ is on the extension of $BA$ through point $A$.

Since $\angle BEF= \angle BEC = 150^{\circ}$ then $\angle CEF=60^{\circ}$

and

Since $EC=EF$ and $\angle CEF=60^{\circ}$ then $\triangle CEF$ is equilateral triangle.

$\angle AFC= \angle BFE + \angle EFC = 10^{\circ}+60{\circ}=70^{\circ}$

$\angle CAF=70^{\circ}$ (sum of $\angle$'s in $\triangle AFC$)

then $CA=CF$ (sides are $=$ opposite $=$ sides)

and

$CA=CE$

Comment: Great answer. You may include in your answer that you are taking a point $F$ on the extended $BA$ so that $CE = EF$ and then automatically $\Delta BEC \cong \Delta BEF.$

Answer (score 1):

In $\triangle ABC$
\begin{align*}
\frac{AC}{\sin40^\circ}&=\frac{BC}{\sin110^\circ}\\
AC&=\frac{\sin40^\circ}{\sin70^\circ}BC
\end{align*}
In $\triangle EBC$
\begin{align*}
\frac{EC}{\sin20^\circ}&=\frac{BC}{\sin30^\circ}\\
EC&=2\sin20^\circ BC
\end{align*}
Now we have to prove
$$2\sin20^\circ=\frac{\sin40^\circ}{\sin70^\circ}$$
It can be proved by using product-to-sum formula.
\begin{align*}
\iff&&2\sin20^\circ&=\frac{\sin40^\circ}{\sin70^\circ}\\
\iff&&\sin20^\circ\sin70^\circ&=\sin40^\circ\\
\iff&&\cos(70^\circ-20^\circ)-\cos(70^\circ+20^\circ)&=\sin40^\circ\\
\iff&&\cos50^\circ&=\sin40
\end{align*}

Comment: Proving in trigonometry is a common method to solve this kind of question although it is not very "geometic". If you want a proof in "pure geometry", a lot of auxiliary lines should be added probably.

Answer (score 0):

One more "adventitious angles" problem...

This one is based on the following trigonometric relationship : $$\frac{\sin 40°}{\sin 110°}=\frac{\sin 20°}{\sin 150°}\tag{1}$$

Indeed, taking advantage of the result of the angle chasing you you have done, let us apply sine law to triangles $ABC$ and $EBC$ (we can assume WLOG that $BC=1$) :

$$\frac{AC}{\sin 40°}=\frac{1}{\sin 110°} \ \ \text{and} \ \  \frac{CE}{\sin 20°}=\frac{1}{\sin 150°} $$

Taking (1) into account, we derive $AC=CE$.

Edit : proof of (1)

(1) is equivalent to :

$$\frac{\sin 40°}{\cos 20°}=\frac{\sin 20°}{\cos 60°},$$

itself equivalent to

$$\frac{2 \sin 20° \cos 20°}{\cos 20°}=\frac{\sin 20°}{\tfrac12}$$

which is true.